Preferred Data Center Country
We are planning to use Salesforce for our upcoming project and would like to know if anyone has experience in selecting the country where account will be hosted. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated

You need to create an case with salesforce support. Here is the article for the How to Create a Case on Salesforce Help

If you haven't purchased Salesforce yet, you should ask your account executive.
